# Wordpress Feed Not working on Single Post

Tags: wordpress

How to display WordPress feed for a single post? I have tried to fix it through plugins but the single post feed is not working.

Is there any plugins or custom code is there? 
The Featured images also not generating.

Full Feed http://odiapua.com/feed/
Single Post Feed [http://odiapua.com/](http://odiapua.com/%E0%AD%A9%E0%AD%A7-%E0%AC%A6%E0%AC%BF%E0%AC%A8%E0%AC%B0%E0%AD%87-%E0%AC%AC%E0%AD%8D%E0%AC%B2%E0%AC%95-%E0%AC%97%E0%AD%8D%E0%AC%B0%E0%AC%BE%E0%AC%A3%E0%AD%8D%E0%AC%9F-%E0%AC%B6%E0%AC%BF%E0%AC%95/feed/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default permalink structure on your blog instead of a pretty-link URL, you can do it this way:

http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/?p=POSTID&feed=rss2&withoutcomments=1

if you are using pretty-links you can do it it this way: http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/YOUR-POST-TITLE/feed/?withoutcomments=1

Comment: But the thumbnails are not coming both for single post and category. Is there any way to remove /?withoutcomments=1 ?

Comment: you can optionally write withoutcomments = 1 by means of a rewrite rule or a function in the functions.php. However, that goes outside the question. the following could do something similar. 'RewriteRule ^your-post-title/feeds$ /your-post-title/feed?withoutcomments=1 [L]' (not tested)

Comment: Is this OK and default in all wordpress website ?